# how to get current loop value in label using c# windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

In my datagridview I have four PDF files. While these four PDF's are getting downloaded it should show that it is downloading the first file out of four file, if it is the second file it should show  that it is downloading the second file out of four files, and os on. It should be done like that until all the files are downloaded into a folder.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= dataGridView1.Row Count;i++ )
{
     label2.Text = i;                      
}
```

Comment: can you suggest some sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run a new Thread to check on the progress of downloading. In this new Thread set the Label status.

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
            while(CheckProgress() <= 4)
            {
               label1.Text = "Downloading " + CheckProgress() + " out of 4 files"; 

            }

            label1.Text = "Downloading Completed!";

        }).Start();
    }
```

Comment: The property `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` is to be used while debugging ([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.checkforillegalcrossthreadcalls(v=vs.110).aspx)). The proper way to solve this, is to use [Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yes you are correct Maarten! :). one can also use timer or Async Programming here. But its too short and simple :D

Comment: How can i make this progress to be displayed only once. Each time when i start my execution the progress of downloading should be displayed only once.